# To Add a record with expected values: Pymongo-Json

Tags: mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

Trying to insert: `{'db001.v064.net': 0.07}` in mongodb using pymongo in python 2.7

I'm getting an error:

> 'Invalid Document: key 'abc.def' must not contain '.'

Comment: What is not understandable that abc.def contains a forbidden period ?! The error message *shows exactly the source of the error*.

Comment: Key of records contain periods.. So how to insert such values to MongoDB?

Comment: @pikkupr Can you show sample documents. so I can edit my answer?

Comment: @user3100115 One such record: {'db001.v064.net': 0.07}

Comment: Can you show us how your document should look like in your collection?
is `{'db001': {'v064': { 'net': 0.07}}}` what you want?

Comment: No, exactly like this - {'db001.v064.net': 0.07}

Comment: @pikkupr user3100115 linked to the description which explicitly says that you cannot use the dollar sign or a period. So the only option left is replace the period with a dummy character (MongoDB suggests the use of unicode codepoint ff0e) when writing and replacing the dummy with the period when reading. There are no other options.

Answer (score 0):

This is because there are  [restrictions](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/limits/#Restrictions-on-Field-Names) on field names in MongoDB

```
collection.insert({'abc': {'def':'some value'}})
```